# How to create a code of clicking the button in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a messagebox and coded so that the excel goes to the specific range where the button exists. But I do not know how to code so that the macro automatically clicks the button.

```
Sub Start()
    Range("A4").Select

<               >
End Sub


Sub MessageBox()

MsgBox "Hi" & vbCrLf & "Professor", _
    vbInformation, "Greetings"

End Sub
```

I need something <                      > in this space but the process to automatically get linked.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: If you want to run the code which belongs to the button you just have to call it. There is no need to click on the button.  Look at [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-sub/)

Answer (score 0):

In your example it looks like you have the name of the macro, and if that's the case it should be easy to just call it. See below

```
Sub Start()
    Range("A4").Select

    Call MessageBox
End Sub

Sub MessageBox()

MsgBox "Hi" & vbCrLf & "Professor", vbInformation, "Greetings"

End Sub
```

However, I'm guessing that doesn't help you because what you're asking doesn't truly make sense. I'm going to guess that maybe by `MsgBox`, you actually mean `Form` or `Command Button`. These look similar but they are distinctly different.

A `MsgBox`is more of an alert to the user with the option to capture a small amount of information back (i.e. yes/no/ok/cancel etc). Clicking on a `MsgBox`will never directly launch another macro. An ANSWER to a `MsgBox`(i.e yes/no) MIGHT determine if another Macro is run based on an if-statement, or if the next line of code is simply just to execute another macro.

If you have a macro running distinctly based on a click, the button is likely a Form or an active X command Button. You need to figure out what macro this object is executing and then you just need to include this in your code. Google "*how to see what macro a form button runs in VBA*" or if it's an active X button, right click on it and hit "View Code". Both of these approaches should drive you to a macro name such as `CommandButton1_Click`.

Unfortunately, you might have to get more fancy as if it's a sheet Commandbutton1_Click you may have to make it public. Hopefully you can insert a call that code in your current macro.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Wow. The coding you put actually is what I wanted.